# Find id of polygon in which points lie

Tags: python, shapely

I am working on a python function. As input I have a dictionary with a set of polygons that cover the entire globe. Each polygon can be accessed by their id, such that plate_polygon[301] gives the polygon with id 301.

I also have a set of points on a regular grid that cover the entire globe that I generate within the function. Now I would like to know in which polygon each of these points lie. Using the Shapely documentation and ChatGPT, I came up with the following function:

```
def get_plate_ids_of_points(plate_polygons):
    
    # Define grid spacing and generate points 
    grid_spacing = 1
    lat = np.arange(-90,90,grid_spacing)
    lon = np.arange(-180,180,grid_spacing)

    # Create a meshgrid of latitudes and longitudes
    lon_grid, lat_grid = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)

    # Flatten the grids to get 1D arrays of all points
    lon_points = lon_grid.flatten()
    lat_points = lat_grid.flatten()

    # Initialise array to store plate_ids
    plate_ids = np.zeros(len(lon_points), dtype=int)

    # Convert plate_polygons to contain Shapely polygons
    polygons = {}  # Dictionary to store Plate ID -> Shapely Polygon
    for plate_id, polygon_coords in plate_polygons.items():
        polygon = Polygon(polygon_coords)
        polygons[plate_id] = polygon

    # Convert points into Shapely Point
    points = [Point(lon_points[i], lat_points[i]) for i in range(len(lat_points))]

    # Determine plate_id for each point
    for i, point in enumerate(points):
        for plate_id, polygon in polygons.items():
            if polygon.contains(point):
                plate_ids[i] = plate_id
                break
    
    points_df = pd.DataFrame({"lat": lat_points, "lon": lon_points, "plate_id": plate_ids})

    return points_df
```

It runs smoothly, but unfortunately, plate_ids remains a list full of zeros. If I print "plate_id" within the nested loop (within the if-statement), it seems to loop over all  polygons, however. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Many thanks!